# How to calculate system clock for ticks? I need to fire the timer every 60 secs (Attiny 404)

Tags: embedded, timer, attiny

My timer initialisation

```
void TCA0_init()
{
    TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLA = TCA_SINGLE_CLKSEL_DIV256_gc| TCA_SINGLE_ENABLE_bm; ;  // Set prescaler to 256
    TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLB = TCA_SINGLE_WGMODE_NORMAL_gc;  // Set timer mode to normal
    TCA0.SINGLE.CNT = 0;                              // Initialize the timer count
    TCA0.SINGLE.INTCTRL = TCA_SINGLE_OVF_bm;           // Enable TCA overflow interrupt
   uint16_t ticks = 13020; //Ticks for 1 sec
    TCA0.SINGLE.PER = ticks - 1;
    set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
    sei();
}
```

Below i have attached ISR for the timer above

```c
volatile uint8_t timerCount = 0;
  
ISR(TCA0_OVF_vect)
{ 
    timerCount++;
    
    if (timerCount == 60)  // Fire the timer every 60 seconds (120 overflows)
    //{
        PORTB.OUT &= ~PIN2_bm;
        _delay_ms(125);
        
        PORTB.OUT |= PIN2_bm;
        _delay_ms(125);
        
    
        PORTB.OUT &= ~PIN3_bm;
        
        timerCount = 0;  // Reset the timer count
    
       }

    TCA0.SINGLE.INTFLAGS = TCA_SINGLE_OVF_bm;
}
```

I have added timer count variable because the ticks value is exceeding 16 bit register value.Please have a look into ISR function and let me know if any changes to be made??

Comment: Which version of an ATtiny404 do you have?  CPU clock is  16MHz or 20MHz. For example, if you have a 20MHz version then ticks =( 20MHz/6/256/)* 60s = 781250.  This number is way too large. Even if we set the prescaler to 1024 we need ticks =( 20MHz/6/1024)* 60s = 3.2552kHz * 60s = 195312.  The max we can get is 20s with ticks equal to  ( 20MHz/6/1024)* 20s = 65104 (0xFE50)

Comment: Ok thanks.So with 60 seconds its not possible?.Below i have attached ISR for the timer above and my question is it advisable to take in addition timer count variable??

Comment: ISR       ISR(TCA0_OVF_vect)
{
    static uint8_t timerCount = 0;
    timerCount++;
    
    if (timerCount == 120i h)  // Fire the timer every 60 seconds (120 overflows)
    {
        PORTA.OUT &= ~PIN1_bm;
        _delay_ms(125);
        
        PORTA.OUT |= PIN1_bm;
        _delay_ms(125);
        
        PORTB.OUT &= ~PIN3_bm;
        
        timerCount = 0;  // Reset the timer count
    }
    
    TCA0.SINGLE.INTFLAGS = TCA_SINGLE_OVF_bm;
}

Comment: It is possible to get interrupt every 60s.  But to be able to achieve this you need to change the main clock prescaler.

Comment: But which version of a ATtiny404 do you have?

Comment: where can i find the version from?It is Attiny 404 and i have attached the link of my Attiny specification : https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Microchip-Technology/ATTINY404-SSNR?qs=F5EMLAvA7IAEqD7Aw0z%252B9Q%3D%3D

Comment: Regarding the main clock prescaler ,at present i was using 256  and had written the code  according to it ,although i did the calculation for 60 secs i am not getting the desired output.Can you please tell me what changes do i need to do in my code?

Comment: I have made changes in the code above in the main description.Please have a look at main description for the code.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

> Timer Frequency is 3.33 MHZ and prescaler 256.So according to that Ticks = 3.33MHZ *60/256 = 781249;.Is the calculation Correct?

The calculations are correct but the number is too big to fit into a 16-bit register.
With the current prescaler setting (20MHz/6 -->3.33MHz/256 = 13kHz).
The maximum you can get is the interrupt every 5s when TCA0.SINGLE.PER = 0xFFFF.

But you can easily get around this by adding an additional timer count variable. And set the interrupt to 1s or 1ms.

```c
#define F_CPU 3333333UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define ticks  (13020) // Interrupt every 1s (3.333333MHz/256 * 1s) 

volatile uint8_t timerCount = 0;

void TCA0_init(void);

int main(void)
{
     PORTB.DIR = PIN2_bm|PIN3_bm; // PIN2 and PIN3 as a output
    
     TCA0_init();
      
    while (1) 
    {
    ;   
    }
}

void TCA0_init(void)
{
     TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLA = TCA_SINGLE_CLKSEL_DIV256_gc| TCA_SINGLE_ENABLE_bm; ;  // Set prescaler to 256
     TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLB = TCA_SINGLE_WGMODE_NORMAL_gc;  // Set timer mode to normal
     TCA0.SINGLE.CNT = 0;                              // Initialize the timer count
     TCA0.SINGLE.INTCTRL = TCA_SINGLE_OVF_bm;           // Enable TCA overflow interrupt
     TCA0.SINGLE.PER =  (ticks - 1);
     //set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
     
     sei();
    
}
ISR(TCA0_OVF_vect)
{
    if (60 == timerCount )
    {       
        PORTB.OUT &= ~PIN2_bm;
        _delay_ms(125);
        PORTB.OUT |= PIN2_bm;
        _delay_ms(125);
        timerCount = 0; 
    }
    timerCount++;
   /* The interrupt flag has to be cleared manually */
    TCA0.SINGLE.INTFLAGS = TCA_SINGLE_OVF_bm;
}
```

> where can i find the version from? It is Attiny 404 and i have attached the link of my Attiny specification :

Seems like you bought ATTINY404-SSNR a 20MHz version.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.Got it ,I have made necessary changes to the code above in the description.I have calculated ticks for 1 sec which is 13020  and timer count is fired for every 60 sec.Hope this is what you meant?

Comment: @jackrusselfernandis It is not a good idea to use delay in the interrupt routine. But in this case, it should work.

Comment: Yes its working and the calculation is correct right? the reason i have added delay is the LED needs to blink for 10 secs with 4 HZ and on top of it i will be adding a for loop  .I hope there is not any problem adding a for loop right inside ISR routine?

Comment: Just set a bool in the ISR and handle all delays and loops in main() and clear the bool there.

Comment: No, you can't add 10s for loop in the ISR.

Comment: Yes got it ,handled loops and delays in main function.Its working perfectly.Thank You

Comment: @jackrusselfernandis Can you show us the final version of a program?